# Vue nested routes not displaying their components and no errors

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

When I access URL `profile/admin`, I see the profile component, however, if I try URL `profile/admin/locations` or `profile/admin/map`, I don't load the Map or Locations components. Any ideas why?

The routes in question:

```
import Home from './components/Home.vue';
import Profile from './components/Profile.vue';
import Map from './components/Map.vue';
import Locations from './components/Locations.vue'

export const routes = [
    { path: '', component: Home, name: 'Home'},
    { path: '/profile/:username', component: Profile, name: 'Profile', chilren: [
        { path: '/profile/:username/locations', component: Locations, name: 'Locations'},
        { path: '/profile/:username/map', component: Map, name: 'Map'}
    ]},
];
```

Profile component template:

```
<template>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>Profile</p>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

Location component template:

```
<template>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>Location</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

Map component template:

```
<template>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>Location</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your routes - `chilren` instead of `children`.

You don't need to specify full path in children routes. Correct way of doing:

```
export const routes = [
    { path: '', component: Home, name: 'Home'},
    { path: '/profile/:username', component: Profile, name: 'Profile', children: [
        { path: 'locations', component: Locations, name: 'Locations'},
        { path: 'map', component: Map, name: 'Map'}
    ]},
];
```

Comment: You're absolutely correct. Weird that I didn't get any errors about it though.